# Wireless mouse only works in one USB port

Tags: usb, wireless, keyboard

I´m trying to use one of those cheap wireless mini keyboard/trackpad units with my Raspberry Pi 3B. The device works well if plugged in any PC port and - if I plug the receiver in the right USB port (the first one I plugged it in) - it also works with the Pi.
Problem is: I MUST connect the receiver to another port, but it doesn´t get recognized if plugged in any other port except the first one.
I have another wireless keyboard/mouse combo (normal size) that works OK whatever port I plug its receiver in, so this may not be a driver or USB port issue.
Is there any configuration I can do to make that little keyboard/trackpad work with any USB port?
Needless to say I´m a newbie to Linux.
Thank you in advance.
Otto Carvalho,
Brazil

Comment: please open a terminal. Plug in the wireless mouse adapter to a port where it doesn't work and than enter to the terminal dmesg. It should show what the system complains about. Maybe your ac adapter is to weak.

Comment: Thank you. dmesg shows in red : "usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32" (two times) then "usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 6, error -32", usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 7, error -32" and then "usb 1-1.4: unable to enumerate USB device". Seems that the wireless adapter is not responding (could be at fault) but why everything is OK if I put it on the "right" port? And why does the system start the enumeration at address 6? Could the adapter be hardwired to a specific address that only the "right" port has? Excuse me for too many questions, but I know nothing about USB.

Comment: looks like you pi has som hardware problem. If you have a chance try on another pi

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. It turned out to be two cold weldings in the chip´s little "legs" inside the adapter. The "right" port just bended the board enough to make contact, the other ports didn´t.

Comment: glad you found it

Comment: left over for those later searching for the issue. As discussed
use dmesg on the console between every time you plug in your usb device.
it will tell you if the device can not be detected at all or if causes an issue when plugged in a particular port. When only on a port that can be very probably a hardware issue. If try the same with another pi